# How to make 0 in all column in a specific table where value is null using MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let the table name is "MyTable"

My current data looks like:

[image]

Following, I need after a query on above table:

[image]

Actually I need to update all column where value is "NULL", in a single query.

Comment: Add default constraints on those columns for value 0.

Comment: I have NULL data inserted already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this. 
It is elegant, but it will update all columns in the table. Huge tables might kill the server

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname = 'tablename'
Declare @UptQuery varchar(max)

Select @UptQuery = stuff(T.X.query('name').value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
from 
(Select ','+name + '=ISNULL('+name+', 0)' name from
    sys.columns where object_id = object_id(@TableName) for xml path(''), type) T(X)

exec ('Update ' + @TableName + ' set ' + @UptQuery)
```

**Old answer**
It will go through all columns for a table and update everything with 0 if it is null. It is a lot of updates, and I think it is still better to design the table correctly from the start.

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname = 'tablename'
Declare @ColName sysname

Select name into #temp from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
while(0 < (Select count(1) from  #temp))
BEGIN
  SET ROWCOUNT 1
  Select @ColName = name from #temp
  SET ROWCOUNT 0
  exec('Update ' + @TableName + ' set ' + @ColName + ' = ISNULL('+@ColName+', 0) where ' + @ColName + ' is null')
  delete #temp where name = @ColName
END
```

Comment: Why not just build one query and execute post loop. This would be slow as hell

Comment: I've added a better way that does not require the loop in the first place. Should be more efficient

Comment: Nice, very clever

Answer (score 5):

Use ISNULL if you want to see the NULL as 0. Like this

```
SELECT ISNULL(Column1,0) FROM YourTable
```

or what you need is to update the value as 0 if NULL and keep the value as it is otherwise. these use a case in the update statement. Like this

```
Update YourTable
SET Column1 = CASE WHEN Column1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Column1 END,
Column2 = CASE WHEN Column2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Column2 END
```

and so on for the rest of the columns. Or this is also possible

```
Update YourTable
    SET Column1 = ISNULL(Column1,0),
cOLUMN2 = ISNULL(Column2,0)
```

Comment: i have 19 column in real So i need to write 19 time case .

Comment: Try the last one instead Column1 = ISNULL(Columm1,0)

Comment: I'd rather use `COALESCE()` instead of ISNULL(), since it's ANSI SQL and portable.

Comment: Its an old question. But are you sure that all the columns are a numeric data type?

Answer (score 2):

`Update table
    Set column1 = coalesce (column1,0), ....`

Answer (score 1):

```
   declare @tableName varchar(30)
    set @tableName='MyTable'

    DECLARE @MakeString AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @MakeString= 
    (SELECT cname + ',' AS 'data()' 
    FROM ( select  COLUMN_NAME +'= isnull(['+COLUMN_NAME+'],0)' as cname from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName
                )  as ccc
    FOR XML PATH('')) 

    SET @MakeString = LEFT(@MakeString, LEN(@MakeString) - 1)

    DECLARE @Sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    set @Sql='Update '+@tableName+'
    SET '+@MakeString+''

    EXEC(@Sql);
```

Comment: That is not very nice to mark an answer as accepted, then answer your own question and mark that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Table SET ColumnName1=0 WHERE ColumnName1 IS NULL

...